# UPDATE em PHP executa mas não atualiza

Tags: php

Boa noite!!!
Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo na faculdade, conforme solicitado pelo professor. Inicialmente foi solicitado que fizéssemos um CRUD. De todas as operações, a única que não consegui foi o update. Tenho a impressão que o ID do registro não está sendo recuperado. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue códigos:

Update.php

```html
<?php
  //update.php
   include_once ("conectar.php");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $id = $_POST["id"];

  
    $sql = "UPDATE pessoa SET PessoaNome='$name', PessoaEmail='$email'item.PessoaId = ".$id;
  
    if(mysqli_query($conexao,$sql)){
        $msg = "Atualizado com sucesso!";
    }else{
        $msg = "Erro ao atualizar!";
    }
    mysqli_close($conexao);    
      
    ?>
```

cadastro.html

```html
<div class="page" data-name="cadastro">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
      <div class="left">
        <a href="#" class="link back">
          <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
          <span class="ios-only">Voltar</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">Pessoa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content">
    <form class="list" action="cli.php" method="POST">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-label">ID</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="hidden" name="Pessoaid" id="idPessoa" placeholder="id">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-label">Nome</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="NomePessoa" placeholder="Your name">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content item-input">
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title item-label">E-mail</div>
              <div class="item-input-wrap">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="EmailPessoa" placeholder="E-mail">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <div class="item-content">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">Toggle</div>
            <div class="item-after">
              <label class="toggle toggle-init">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" value="yes"><i class="toggle-icon"></i>
                                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="row">
        <input class="col button button-fill" name="excluir" type="submit" id="excluir" value="Excluir!" />
        <input class="col button button-fill" name="salvar" type="submit" id="salvar" value="Salvar!" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

ws.js

```html
function atualizaPessoa(id){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  url: 'http://localhost/appaula/ws/update.php?id='+id,
  dataType: "text",
  async: false,
  success: function (result) {
   app.dialog.alert("Atualizado com sucesso");
  },
  error: function() {
   app.dialog.preloader('Erro ao atualizar pessoas');
  },
 });
}
```

Desculpe, mas sou bem iniciante no assunto, então perdoem qualquer coisa.
Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: Olá, Boa noite!!! O cli.php seria o update.php, já o ws.js especificamente a function atualizaepessoa, está sendo chamada na inicialização da pagina, através deste trecho de código à seguir, que executaria o atualizapessoa no momento em que o usuário clicar em salvar.

Comment: $$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="cadastro"]', function (e) {
    retornaPessoa(idPessoa);
    $('#excluir').click(function(){
    app.dialog.confirm('Excluir Cadastro???', function () {
        deletePessoa(idPessoa);
    app.dialog.alert('Concluído!');
            });
        });     
            $('#salvar').click(function(){
            atualizaPessoa(idPessoa);
             });
});

Comment: erro de sintaxe na declaração UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Localize a seguinte linha do seu codigo:

$sql = "UPDATE pessoa SET PessoaNome='$name', PessoaEmail='$email'item.PessoaId = ".$id;

Substitua por algo como isto:
$sql = "UPDATE pessoa SET PessoaNome='$name', PessoaEmail='$email' WHERE PessoaId='$id'";

Isso ja deve fazer o update funcionar, Abçs.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou corretamente após realização do ajuste sugerido!!!